# Internationalization Web Number-Symbols

Tags: web, numbers, internationalization, symbols

do I need to use another number-symbols when I want my webpage to be accessible in other countries? According to Microsoft there are different shape of numbers: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting#:~:text=formatting%20for%20details.-,The%20character%20used%20as%20the%20thousands%20separator,thousands%20separator%20is%20a%20space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting#:%7E:text=formatting%20for%20details.-,The%20character%20used%20as%20the%20thousands%20separator,thousands%20separator%20is%20a%20space).

I have been searching since a few days to get a clear answer but I cant find some. Also, on most international websites/apps I only ever see the digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 although the digits for the language actually look different. That unsettles me. I feel like many websites/apps just ignore this fact. Can anybody help me further? Also do I need to know how to activate foreign symbols in html?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure what language you are translating/typing in HTML. But here is an example of what you can use as a guide to certain scripts in Arabic: https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/mideast/arabic/arabicchart/

You may also need to use a converter. For example, I type Chinese on my website by typing the characters into a character to unicode converter. Then I copy and paste the unicode to my HTML text.